# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list

Tags: android-studio, dex

As per title, getting limit hit after upgrading AndroidStudio from 3.0.1 to 3.1,

no issue before.

Detail of the error:

## methods: 66320 > 65536

Message{kind=ERROR, text=Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.

## methods: 66320 > 65536, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled false
        applicationId "com.example.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            //shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            //minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            //shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    // Necessary to force the use of a specific version (on all the builds)
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //Android
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.3'


    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'glide', version: '3.7.0' 


    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.2.0'
    implementation 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
    implementation 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.0.0'


    implementation 'de.javagl:obj:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'



    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Why downvote? At least say the reason or will be full of haters also here very soon? We are here to discussing and exchanging thoughts, knowledge and experiences and if someone does not offend or make some bad jokes I do not see the point to downvote him and not giving him the opportunity to be part of the community with what learn here and from other sources.

Answer (score 6):

Try add

```
defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true 
    ...
}
```

in gradle. It fix my problem.

documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Error was in some png aapt was trying to compress and found not correct.

Added

```
 aaptOptions{
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
```

in gradle solved the issue.

Hope this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

delete -rf you used gradle version filepath(.gradle/warpper/dists/gradle-**.-all).
it fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the `build.gradle` file from *app* level:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add implementation `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3` into the Gradle build, then `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig`.

Answer (score -1):

Add dependency in `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

In `build.gradle`'s `defaultConfig` section, add:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: Hey, and welcome to SO :) I have edited your answer so it is easier to read. Don't hesitate to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in order to format content.

Comment: adding [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) would improve this answer. Not everyone knows what multiDexEnable means